# OpenAM J2EE Agent 3.2.0 SNAPSHOT - ERROR

Tags: java, security, single-sign-on, openam, opensso

I have a requirement to implement Authentication using OpenAM J2EE Agent. I’m using JBOSS v7.1.1. The current production version of J2EE Agent (3.1.0) does not support JBOSS 7 (unless hacks are implemented). So, I used the 3.2.0 SNAPSHOT version from Community website to run J2EE Agent on JBOSS 7.1.1. I was successfully able to run the agent. The agent intercepts the initial (i.e. when no token exists) request and forwards it to OpenAM server. But the redirection from OpenAM Server after successful login fails and the below message is logged in Agent DEBUG logs. My question is whether someone has managed to get latest 3.2.0 SNAPSHOT version working on JBOSS 7 and whether the interception of requests and redirection works properly.

```
amFilter:08/23/2013 10:54:48:229 AM EDT: Thread[http--0.0.0.0-9100-1,5,main]
ERROR: URLFailoverHelper: No URL is available at this time
amFilter:08/23/2013 10:54:48:230 AM EDT: Thread[http--0.0.0.0-9100-1,5,main]
ERROR: AmFilter: a server error occurred.
[AgentException Stack]
com.sun.identity.agents.arch.AgentServerErrorException: No URL is available at this time
    at com.sun.identity.agents.common.URLFailoverHelper.getAvailableURL(URLFailoverHelper.java:155)
    at com.sun.identity.agents.common.URLFailoverHelper.getAvailableURL(URLFailoverHelper.java:82)
    at com.sun.identity.agents.filter.AmFilterRequestContext.getLoginURL(AmFilterRequestContext.java:835)
    at com.sun.identity.agents.filter.AmFilterRequestContext.getAuthRedirectURL(AmFilterRequestContext.java:294)
    at com.sun.identity.agents.filter.AmFilterRequestContext.getAuthRedirectURL(AmFilterRequestContext.java:267)
    at com.sun.identity.agents.filter.AmFilterRequestContext.getAuthRedirectResult(AmFilterRequestContext.java:413)
    at com.sun.identity.agents.filter.AmFilterRequestContext.getAuthRedirectResult(AmFilterRequestContext.java:395)
    at com.sun.identity.agents.filter.SSOTaskHandler.doSSOLogin(SSOTaskHandler.java:268)
    at com.sun.identity.agents.jboss.v40.AmJBossSSOTaskHandler.doSSOLogin(AmJBossSSOTaskHandler.java:76)
    at com.sun.identity.agents.filter.SSOTaskHandler.process(SSOTaskHandler.java:110)
    at com.sun.identity.agents.filter.AmFilter.processTaskHandlers(AmFilter.java:194)
    at com.sun.identity.agents.filter.AmFilter.isAccessAllowed(AmFilter.java:157)
    at com.sun.identity.agents.filter.AmAgentBaseFilter.doFilter(AmAgentBaseFilter.java:75)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:280)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:248)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:275)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:161)
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:397)
    at org.jboss.as.web.security.SecurityContextAssociationValve.invoke(SecurityContextAssociationValve.java:153)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:155)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:102)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:109)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:368)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.process(Http11Processor.java:877)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Protocol$Http11ConnectionHandler.process(Http11Protocol.java:671)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$Worker.run(JIoEndpoint.java:930)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:722)
```

Firefox browser throws: 302 MOVED TEMPORARILY. I believe it runs into a loop.